# Is it possible to right align only a portion of the text in a UItableView Cell?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uilabel

I'm trying working on a quiz app which has a leaderboard on one view. I'm trying to get the user's username to be left align, with their score right aligned. Is there anyway to do this? I tried using tab characters but it was a total mess.

Here's a picture of what the view looks like:

[image: Scnreeshot]

Comment: Please share your code or storyboard/xib screenshot of your view controller.I would suggest you take two different labels in a custom UITableView cell. One right and left label.

Comment: You can create a two label. One is for username and another one is for score. For label you can set the text alignment.

Comment: Either you can create two label as @BoominadhaPrakashM suggested or you can use attributed string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple with custom cell and two different labels.

[image: name]

[image: score]

Answer (score 0):

If u give equal width constraints to both the label this issue could be solved to some extend. But when the content of 1st label is large u might not see the full content.

Answer (score 0):

It's too simple. Use two different labels, one for username (left aligned text) and another for score (right aligned text).

Also, set **content compression priority** for one of both label, according to your requirement for data visibility when there is long texts in user name.

Look at these snapshots:

Labels with default `content compression resistance priority`

[image]

I changed `content compression resistance priority` for label `blablabla blablabla`, from `750` to `749`.

Result is:

[image]

For more details see Apple document: [Setting Content-Hugging and Compression-Resistance Priorities](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH10-SW1)

Answer (score 0):

It will be much easier if you subclass UITableViewCell and custom it. Use one UILabel for name and another for score, for example: lbName with left alignment and lbScore with right alignment.